# Coworker updated CSS but not SASS - Is there a way to compare?

Tags: css, sass

A coworker of mine had updated a css file in a theme as a quick fix for a client, but had not updated the scss file. Is there a tool or way to compare the two files and make updates to the scss file as necessary?

Comment: If you're using version control, can't you just compare the compiled CSS to the CSS that your co-worker modified? There are several diff utilities that you can use. Most version control systems have it built in.

Comment: there are tons of "diff tools" you can use

Comment: Well, if you have the old file too, you could compare using a diff tool for the changes. Then just update the sass by hand is prob the quickest fix.

Comment: The guys are all correct. Here is your chance to build the first tool of its kind Dan. You'll be famous!

Comment: I always use the /*  */ comments in my sass files to know where I am in the CSS. Think about that going forward.